# PHP SQL Query to get the most common value in the table

Tags: php, sql, pdo, count

I'm trying to have my query count the rows and have it return the most common name in that list, then from that it counts how many times that name appears and outputs the name and the amount of times its there
This is the code I'm using:

```
$vvsql = "SELECT * FROM votes WHERE sid=? ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1";
$vvresult = $db->prepare($vvsql);
$vvresult->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$vvcount = $vvresult->rowCount();
    foreach ($vvresult->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) { 
            echo $row['username'];
            echo $vvcount;
    }
```

However, it just displays the first username in the table and counts up the entire table. I'm pretty new to this so I'm sorry if this is a bad post or if it didn't make much sense.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I have 3 rows in the table votes, 2 are from the username Test and 1 is with the username Test2. I would like to query this and have it find the most common username and how many times that username appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would seem to want:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM votes 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note the `GROUP BY`.  You may also want to filter by `sid` but your question makes no mention of that.

Comment: This worked for most of it however it still only counts 1 with vvcount even though there's two rows with the username

Comment: @Calbyy If you want the count you need to add that to the query. Also `rowcount` won't give you that, aggregate functions aggregate, so you only have 1 row.

Comment: $row['COUNT(*)']
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-group-by.php

Answer (score 1):

```
select username, count(*) as c 
FROM votes 
GROUP BY username 
ORDER BY c DESC
```

Comment: Please explain this code/answer a bit to help OP and future users.

Comment: Sorry if I sound dumb but how do i then display that count(*) with the number and username